# How i can check for server not reply in android?

Tags: android, json

I am building an articles reading android application like TechChurn. I am fetching data from server in the form of json.

I am parsing title, author name and articles-content from json and displaying it in list-view.
The problem i am facing is that i need a toast when there is no response from server end means that if i request some data from server and just suppose that time server is down and not replying that time application can toast 
here is my code -

```
JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(URL,
new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
    // Parsing json
    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
        try {
            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
            Movie movie = new Movie();
            movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
            movie.setDate(obj.getString("date"));
            movieList.add(movie);
```

Comment: `response.getStatus()` has meaningful info about this. Do some research.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a `Response.ErrorListener`?

```
    Response.Listener<JSONArray> listener = new Response.Listener<JSONArray>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
            // Parsing json
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
            try {
                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                Movie movie = new Movie();
                movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                movie.setDate(obj.getString("date"));
                movieList.add(movie);

            // the rest of your logic ...
        }
    };

    Response.ErrorListener errorListener = new Response.ErrorListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Oops!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };

   JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(URL, listener, errorListener);
```

Comment: What is response.getStatus here it is giving error.

Comment: Changed my answer, please check.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can simply try to catch IOexception:

```
} catch (IOException 
         Log.e(TAG, "Failed to register on attempt " + i + ":" + e);
          if (i == MAX_ATTEMPTS) {
          break;
                }
```

Comment: This is not working! properly. i had toast a message  if (i == MAX_ATTEMPTS) but when i am running it there is not toast